Received signal SNR measurement
I am simulating the communication system shown below. I want to analyse the Fractionally-spaced Equalizer performance through BER vs SNR simulations. To meet a target SNR, I scale the noise power accordingly. My doubt is where to measure the signal and noise powers. I have shown at three points below.
I am measuring power as the mean squared value of the oversampled data.
In all works, SNR is measured after the matched filter (matched to both channel and transmit pulse), as this operation maximises SNR. But, I am matching only to the transmit pulse. Also, we have coloured noise at the Matched filter output.
But if I were to compare the performance of the equalizer, I would plot the BER vs (SNR at the input of the equalizer).


The approach I use for these situations is what I refer to as an "all-sample EVM" where I compute the SNR by scaling and delay matching the waveform at a test point in the system with a reference copy of that waveform as it would appear ideally at that location, using a correlation coefficient. This approach can determine equivalent noise figures, SNR and EVM at any point along the way in the transmitter or receiver.  See DSP.SE #67183 for more details on EVM)
Ultimately we only care about the EVM at the correct decision samples after the matched filter and after all timing, carrier, and gain correction and channel equalization has been completed (the EVM just prior to decision), but the above approach is effective in modularizing components and testing that they meet requirements, as well as system test and verification on final hardware.
I have optimized a tool for doing this that provides the necessary gain and delay matching with distortion less than -100 dB, which is part of my online course "DSP for Software Radio": you can find more info and to register at this link: https://dsprelated.com/courses
